# Calling java method in Javascript loop function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am running a javascript function which is under a for loop.
The called javascript function calls a java method with the passed parameters.
I don't know why java method not execute each time javascript function in loop is called. But it executes after loop has completed. So, called java method doesn't follow the order of passed parameter.
The sample code of my program will look like this:

```
function firstfunction() {
    var x = 5;
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        secondfunction(j, x);
    }
}

function secondfunction(j, x) {
    JavaClass.Javamethod(j, x, callback);
}
```

Java method do some calculation and return some value as callback. I want my code to call the java method and return the value and then go in javascript loop to take the next parameter and so on.

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - Java on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. before the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, after the browser receives the already generated response. So you **cannot** directly access Java code from Javascript.

Comment: With Javascript every time you send to the server (Java) and it returns you reload the entire page.
For what you want, you would have to use Ajax, it is a JavaScript extension, which allows you to exchange information with a server and update part of the contents of a web without having to reload the web page completely

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly call the Java method/function once JavaScript code is executed, to execute that you have to use JavaScript ajax function which is used to execute backend programming language function for eg. Java method based on the url you defined of that method and passed the parameters in the ajax 'data' which is required by the java method and in ajax response you will get the return value of that java method.